# Php can I use foreach with next() function?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

As I read the next() php function forwards the array pointer to next item. I am not sure if I can use next() in foreach cycle and if next() will not affect the pointer for foreach. When I test it in simple example

```
$a = [1,2,3,4];
foreach( $a as $i )
{
    echo 'item ' . $i . '<br>';
    $next = next($a);
    echo 'next item ' . $next . '<br>';
}
```

it seem the foreach is not affected by next(). Result is

`item 1
next item 2
item 2
next item 3
item 3
next item 4
item 4`

Is it right? Can I use next in foreach without fear of affecting array pointer in foreach?

Comment: Why would you use `next` at all?

Comment: I advise you to use `continue` if you want to go to the next iteration. Or use the `foreach($data as $index => $key)` syntax and use `$data[$index + 1]` if you want to access the next value without go to the next iteration. Using next can be really painfull to debug

Comment: What's your php version? And I think its bad way. Dont work like this, use array copy or continue.

Comment: Yes you can. it won't affect on the foreach, but you should find a cleaner way for your subject.

Comment: From docs. "In PHP 7, foreach does not use the internal array pointer". [foreach docs](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)  And dont use $data[$index + 1] to change value when work by value because "When used in the default by-value mode, foreach will now operate on a copy of the array being iterated rather than the array itself. This means that changes to the array made during iteration will not affect the values that are iterated." [migrate php7 docs](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php)

Comment: I need it because I want to compare some values of current and next item and then make some action according the comparison. Next() looks like a simple way to do it.